# FireFox Pop Up Blocker breaks javascript app when using .focus()

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I'm having a problem with FireFox popup blocker and this javascript code.  Since FireFox blocks the popup, the statement `.focus()` throws an error because the window isn't open, so any scripts after will not run due to this error. In other words, if FireFox popup blocker blocks the window opened in this code, which in turn breaks the app, any code after `.focus()` will not work.  Console gives an error as `win is null`

```
var win = window.open(url,window,options)
win.focus()
alert('hi');
```

I wasn't able to find any code to check if a window is open before running the `.focus()` code, anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var win = window.open(url,window,options)
if( win != null)
    win.focus();
alert('hi');
```

This should work. You have to check if `win` is defined. If not, dont call any method on it.

Answer (score 1):

or you could use:

```
var win = window.open(url,window,options)
try{
win.focus()
}
catch(ex){
  alert(ex.message);
}
alert('hi');
```